# Cordova / Kendo app crashing log

Tags: android, ios, logging, kendo-ui, telerik

I have an app that is crashing from time to time when it starts (Android/IOS). Where can I find a Log on the device so I can understand whats going on.

Device: Android / IOS
Type: Hybrid -Cordova/Kendo mobile-